# Newbie question regarding the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-numbers

In geometrical representation of complex numbers I often see the so called "imaginary axis" depicted as an axis containing real numbers i.e. $\text{Im}(z)$ - the $i$ itself isn't included. But in other sources they write the numbers with the $i$. So which one is right? Isn't the fact we have added an axis (i.e. extending the dimension) already suggest we have $i$ "applied" to each point in the plane? I know that this question sounds stupid but this uncertainty makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually matter, as long as they are consistent with their notation.

$a+bj$ (yes I use j) can be expressed as $z=\Re(z)+\Im(z)j$

You just imagine a number $z=x+yj$ as the vector $[x,y]$. They add the same. Multiplication of these "vectors" would be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Im (z) is the "y" coordinate of $z$ on the complex plane (suppose $z = x + iy$).

Answer (score 0):

The real plane $\mathbb R^2$ serves as a model of the compex number field $\mathbb C$.  In this correspondence, one associates the complex number $a+bi$ with the point $(a,b)$ of the real plane.  In this model, the purely imaginary numbers $bi$ correspond to the points $(0,b)$, which form the $y$-axis of $\mathbb R^2$.  This is why the $y$-axis is referred to as the *imaginary* axis.